# DataTable dt is inaccessible due its protection level

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I want to add a row from my DateTimePicker, TextBoxes and ComboBox (which are on form2) to DGV (form1), and now I get the message:

> 'Overzicht.File.dt' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

How do I solve this?

This is form1

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Javell_Administratie_Software
{
    public partial class Overzicht : Form
    {
        public Overzicht()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Overzicht1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        }

        public DataTable table
        {
            set
            {
                File myFile = new File();
                table = myFile.dt;
            }

//above at myFile.dt its giving me the error

            get
            {
                return table;
            }
        }        

        public class File
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            public void RekeningenOverzicht()
            {
                Overzicht oz = new Overzicht();
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in oz.Overzicht1.Columns)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(col.Name);
                    col.DataPropertyName = col.Name;
                }
                ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                oz.Overzicht1.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
    
        public void AddDataTableRow()
        {
            Toevoegen tv = new Toevoegen();
            Object row = new Object[]
            { 
              tv.dateTimePicker1.Value, tv.textBox1.Text,             
              tv.textBox2.Text, tv.textBox3.Text, tv.textBox4.Text,
              tv.textBox5.Text, tv.comboBox1.Text
            };
            table.Rows.Add(row);
            Overzicht1.DataSource = table;
            Overzicht1.Update();
            tv.Close();
        }

        public void Toevoegen1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Toevoegen tv = new Toevoegen();
            tv.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

This is form2

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Javell_Administratie_Software
{

    public partial class Toevoegen : Form
    {

        public Toevoegen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }       

        public void Toevoegen2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Overzicht oz = new Overzicht();
            oz.AddDataTableRow();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `dt` in your `File` class is private. Also your property will cause a stackoverflow exception.

Comment: Off-topic, but it seems you need to take a look at [Naming Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx).  `table` is not suitable property name, also `File` is not a suitable class name. Also `Javell_Administratie_Software` is not suitable for namespace.

Comment: do you have a solution for the getter?

Comment: Not only the getter, also the setter will cause a stackoverflow exception. While your property name is `table` you are setting `table = something;` in setter and getting `return table;` in getter. It makes another call to the setter/getter over and over again.

Comment: ok now i know the problem but not the solution, do you have an example maybe how to fix this?

Comment: You need a private field and in property getter and setter, get and set it. Read more about [Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) and [Fields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx).

Comment: thanx that solved the problem but i'm getting a new on in this line:

     table.Rows.Add(row); 

it gives NullReferencException was Unhandled

Comment: Your code probably have changed and you need to ask a new question about it. But the setter has another problem too, usually you should use `value` in setter and assign it to the private field, but you totally neglect the `value` in setter.

Comment: i will ask it as new question with my code added. Thnax for you'r great help!

Comment: By the way @BugFinder correctly answered your question and it would be great if you accept the answer. Other points which I mentioned was not about the exception which you received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want DataTable dt from your class File to be visible you need to set them as such

```
Public DataTable dt = new DataTable();
Public DataSet ds = new DataSet();
```

If they arent public they cant be seen outside the class

Comment: thanx this solves the first problem but now i walking against the problem Reza tells me above aboute the getter.